# Reversing a hash, getting its keys, and sorting

Tags: perl, hash

I'm still learning Perl, so there's probably a more efficient way of doing this. I'm trying to take a hash, reverse it so $values => $keys, grab the new key (the old value) and then sort those keys.

Here's the code in question:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys reverse %hash){

...}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that reverse %hash will return a hash type, which is what keys is looking for. However, I get the following error:

Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not reverse)

I've tried putting parentheses around reverse %hash, but still get the same thing.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl functions can either return scalar values or lists; there is no explicit hash return type
(You can call `return %hash` from a subroutine, but Perl implicitly unrolls the key-value pairs from the hash and returns them as a list).

Therefore, the return value of `reverse %hash` is a list, not a hash, and not suitable for use as an argument to `keys`. You can force Perl to interpret this list as a hash with the `%{{}}` cast:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %{{reverse %hash}}) { ...
```

You could also sort on the values of the hash by saying

```
foreach my $key (sort values %hash) { ...
```

Using `values %hash` is subtly different from using `keys %{{reverse %hash}}` in that `keys %{{reverse %hash}}` will not return any duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is probably way beyond my level (I'm still working my way through Learning Perl 6th Ed), but where can I read more about using %{{}}. Sadly google doesn't have anything for that term.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html There are also a few more links in the "See also" section at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `keys` must be a hash, array or expression, not a list. If you did

```
keys { reverse %hash }
```

you would get the result you expect, because the brackets create an anonymous hash. Parens, on the other hand, only change the precedence. Or, in this case they are probably considered related to the function `keys()`, as most perl functions have optional parens.

Also, if you just want the values of the hash, you can use:

```
values %hash
```

See the documentation for [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) and [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand the use of reverse on a hash fully before posting. From the perldoc page for reverse it looks like reverse unwinds the original hash and then builds a new one. However, I would still think that this new hash would be the return value of reverse.

I tried adding the brackets around reverse and %hash but still had the same problem.

Comment: I don't know if you are saying you still have a problem. `reverse` returns a *list*, not a hash. A list is basically `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`, and if you tried to use that with `keys`, it would take the first value `1`, try to use it, and discard the rest.

Comment: `{reverse %hash}` is a reference to a hash, which is also not a suitable argument for `keys` (I stand corrected -- you can use a hash reference with Perl >=v5.14)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're describing exactly the situation [in this example](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-reverse.html):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (one   => 1, two  => 2, three => 3, four => 4);

%hash = reverse %hash;

foreach my $key (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash) {
    print "$key=>$hash{$key}, ";
}
print "\n";

# it displays: 1=>one, 2=>two, 3=>three, 4=>four
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this works, I was more interested in knowing why my posted code didn't act as expected. Again, thanks!

Comment: @chris, Cause you didn't pass a hash to `keys`, just like the error message said.

Answer (score 3):

Pre 5.14, `keys` returns the keys of hash. That requires a hash. You didn't provide one. `reverse` doesn't return a hash. In fact, it's impossible to return a hash as only scalars can be returned. (Internally, Perl can put hashes directly on the stack, but that will never be visible to the user without causing a "Bizarre" error message.) This error is detected at compile-time.

5.14 is more flexible. It will also accept a reference to a hash. (It will also accept arrays and references to arrays, but that's not relevant here.) References are scalars, so they can be returned by functions. Your code will actually make it to run-time, but whatever your `reverse` returns in scalar context won't a reference to a hash that doesn't exist, so your code will die at that point.

---

Do you have a reason to want to reverse the hash?

```
foreach my $key (sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash) {
   my $val = $hash{$key};
   ...
}
```

If you do,

```
foreach my $val (sort keys %{ { reverse %hash } }) {
   # No access to original key
   ...
}
```

or

```
my %flipped = reverse %hash;
foreach my $val (sort keys %flipped) {
   my $key = $flipped{$val};
   ...
}
```